# Pointing last year's website to different url

Tags: web, redirect

I am using Bluehost to host my website.
Website needs to be refreshed and start anew each year, but I want to keep the current website in subdirectory.

How can I point current website (**example.com**) to something like **example.com/2020-2021** and start creating new website in **example.com**? while keeping the same layouts

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the website's html directly, try [this](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-redirect-a-web-page-in-html.html). It should redirect the page automatically.